# How can I use multiple condition in v-if in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my code:

**JavaScript**

```
let Names = [
    {
        Name: "Josh"
        FullName: ""
    },
    {
        Name: "Jonathan"
        FullName: null
    },
    {
        Name: "James"
        FullName: "James Johnson"
    }
];
```

**Index.Vue**

```
<ul>
    <li
        v-for="item in Names" 
        v-if=" item.FullName != null || item.FullName != '' "
    >
     {{FullName}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

This `v-if=" item.FullName != null || item.FullName != '' "` does not work, Why? How can I put two condition inside a `v-if`?

Comment: You should consider a computed property for this, by the way.

Comment: @ceejayoz That was my first thought, but it's actually inside a `v-for` so you couldn't really use a computed, but you could use a method.

Comment: Should i use computed or methods to this? I just want to not show `li` if `FullName` is `''` (empty string) or `null` . Just that =x

Comment: Try `v-if="!!item.FullName"`

Comment: Wow! It worked, what it means?

Comment: in javascript any empty,null or undefined values are falsy.. So, `!!` double negates and returns an actual boolean value representing if they are any of those falsy values or not.

Comment: Hmmm is this the same as `v-if="item.FullName"` ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Maybe it's the way you are treating empty strings as false-ly values and `||` is saying: show fullname if any of the two (left/right) expressions are true, which is not what you want I think.

Try this instead:

```
 <li v-for="item in Names" v-if="item.FullName !== null && item.FullName !== ''">
```

Also, judging from your code, `{{ FullName }}` should be `{{ item.FullName }}`

Comment: I have to use the operator `||`, i tried to add one more `=`, but did not work :(

Comment: though the answer is right, it is a bad practice to use v-for and v-if on the same element. refer to Kamocsai Kamo András answer

Comment: @jedi rigth. this is stated in the documentation - https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/index.html#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential

Comment: Is it just my eyes or is there an odd number of unmatched `"` in the answer above?

Comment: @MCCCS definitely not your eyes :)

Answer (score 10):

Samayo's answer is right, and maybe this question a little old, but there are some issues:

First, please *avoid* v-for with v-if in the same element!
(source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential)

And second, if you want to use v-if with || operator, just use a computed, or simple method.

Finally, I think its the better way if you use camelCase, not the PascalCase for the variants or for object's keys.

```
<li v-if="fullNameIsExist(item)">
  <span>{{ item.fullName }}
```

And if you use a method:

```
methods: {
  fullNameIsExist (item) {
    if (![null, ''].includes(item.fullName)) return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) that evaluates all of the conditionals then have a single v-if for your computed property.  It will make your template cleaner and the computed property will be [self documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

Answer (score 2):

The best way is using computed stuff

```
computed: {
    condition() {
      this.FullName;
      return this.FullName !== null && this.FullName !== '';
    }
  }
```

and is it as condition

```
<li v-for="item in Names" v-if="condition>
```

and instead of `{{ FullName }}` you should use `{{ item.FullName }}`
You were almost right with condition, but error was because of `{{ FullName }}` that's why you should write `{{ item.FullName }}` and because of `||` instead you better might use `&&`
Also you can do the stuff like this:

```
 <li v-for="item in Names" v-if="item.FullName !== null && item.FullName !== ''>
```

Comment: You should not use v-for and v-if at the same time: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy.

```
<li v-for="item in Names" v-if="!!item.FullName>
```

In Javascript, `!!0` will return `false`, `!!1` will return `true`, `!!""` will return `false`, `!!"a"` will return `true`and `!!null` will return `false`

Comment: don't use v-for and v-if together in Vue2.  see documentation link in above answer.