# Vue.js: how to use the logical Operators in a template?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would simply like to use 2 different `v-if` into the same div, as the following:

Actually I have this code:

```
<div class="o-overlay" v-if="show">
    <div class="o-overlay__bg" @click="hide"></div>
</div>
```

Containing only one **v-if**.

And I would like to use 2 or more **v-if** inside the same condition, like for instance:

```
<div class="o-overlay" v-if="show" v-if="visible">
    <div class="o-overlay__bg" @click="hide"></div>
</div>
```

But it give me a lot of error and I would simply like to learn the correct way to use it. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can do `show || visible` which the item will show if either are true or `show && visible` where you will only show if both are true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add-more-than-one-v-if-with-different-conditions-for-one-div-without-duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594222/add-more-than-one-v-if-with-different-conditions-for-one-div-without-duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS Multiple Condition v-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515308/vuejs-multiple-condition-v-if)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use them in the same `v-if` directive e.g.

`&&` = Logical Operator `AND`

`||` = Logical Operator `OR`

`&&` means both conditions have to be true for the div to show.

```
<div class="o-overlay" v-if="show && visible">
    <div class="o-overlay__bg" @click="hide"></div>
</div>
```

`||` means only one of the conditions have to be true for the div to show.

```
<div class="o-overlay" v-if="show || visible">
    <div class="o-overlay__bg" @click="hide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ced learn more about that here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me