# how to reuse "step===1" template inside a "step===2"

Tags: html, vue.js

Here I have written two steps one is "step===1" and other one is "step===2". So here i wants to reuse step1 template to step2. That means we have step one template and at step1 we click on next button so at next step i want to show the same template like reusing..

```html
<div v-if="step === 1">

    <h1>Step One</h1>
    <h4>Address</h4>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="address">

    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="city">

    <label>State</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="state">

    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>

 </div>
<div v-if="step === 2">
    reuse step===1 template here
</div>
```

**vue.js**

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            address: null,
            city: null,
            state: null
        }
    },
    methods:{
    prev() {
      this.step--;
    },
    next() {
      this.step++;
    },
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You can separate them in two components (StepChild and StepParent), StepChild will be reusable, you can pass the data to the child StepChild as props, and call it twice in the StepParent for each step

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56702731/1264804) in particular is probably your best approach.